# how to create a vector drawable for a document in a circle in Android

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

how can I draw a vector drawable of a document in a circle which looks like this please or something similar

[image]

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your question with a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44225497/5595926).

You can do this using the `layer-list` technique.

Comment: Hello thank you for that, how can I draw lines in place of inner circle please?

Comment: <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_vector_drawable" />

It will be useful to use the relevant icon as a vector.

Comment: sample usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36103941/5595926